# How to intercept an outgoing Text Message on Android and notify user

Tags: android, sms

Is it possible on Android to intercept an outgoing text message and show a "prompt" to the user before it goes out?

For example, can I look at a message, do a spell check, then prompt the user to change the spelling of something before the message is actually sent?

Or, for another example, if I were to create a game around text messaging, and the format of the text needed to be changed a little before going to the receiver (like adding a comma).

Is this even possible?  If so, where do I start to learn how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible on Android to intercept an outgoing text message and show a "prompt" to the user before it goes out?

AFAIK, no. `SmsManager` -- what everything on the device uses to send SMS messages -- sends them directly. There are no broadcast `Intents` or plug-ins or anything to intercept these messages. In part, I imagine this is for privacy reasons.